# Safe to use matching CFBridging calls to transfer in and out of ARC for non CF types?

Tags: objective-c, c, automatic-ref-counting, chipmunk, toll-free-bridging

I'm writing a game using the Chipmunk physics engine, and I'd like to store a pointer to an Objective-C object in every body's `userData` field. I know I need to use a bridging cast to cast between `id` and `void *`, but I'm not sure the way I'm doing it is safe:

```
// When body is created
cpBody *body = cpBodyNew(...);
UserData *userData = [[UserData alloc] init];
cpBodySetUserData(body, CFBridgingRetain(body));

...

// When body is destroyed
UserData *userData = cpBodyGetUserData(body);
CFBridgingRelease(userData);
cpBodyFree(body);
```

This code seems to work, but I've also read that you're only supposed to use `CFBridging*()` on objects that can be toll-free bridged to Core Foundation types.  Since `UserData` is derived from `NSObject`, and `NSObject` isn't on the [list of toll-free bridged types](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html), I seem to be breaking that rule.

Is my code okay because I eventually call `CFBridgingRelease` and don't try to pass the object to any other Core Foundation functions, or is there another way I should be going about transferring Objective-C objects in and out of C?

Comment: Perhaps you could also use bridge casts. To set: (__bridge void *) myData, to get: (__bridge id) myData()

Comment: @JasperBlues, that works if the `UserData` object is guaranteed to survive at least as long as any of these `void*` references. It doesn't extend the lifetime to make it so, though, whereas the `CFBridgingRetain()` does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's safe.  `NSObject` is toll-free bridged to a generic `CFTypeRef`.  Also, I'm assuming you aren't calling any other Core Foundation functions on the `void*`, so it hardly matters.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! It's okay even though `NSObject` isn't on the [list of toll-free bridged types](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html)? I updated my question to clarify the concern.

Comment: Here's a statement from a Cocoa framework engineer: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/95007-toll-free-bridging-of-nsobject.html#95680

Comment: Perfect! I appreciate the help.

Comment: @godel9: With "Jump to definition" in Xcode you can also see that CFBridgingRetain/CFBridgingRelease are just inline function wrappers for __bridge_retained/__bridge_transfer.